# sudo apt-get update doesn't work

Tags: terminal, apt

I am using ubuntu 14.04 LTS. when I run **sudo apt-get update** command in terminal,  following error will appear

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)

E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

what should I do?

Comment: :please logout and try again.If still not successful restart the system.

Comment: Yeah! Now its working fine :D. But why that error was happened before I restart?

Comment: :I think it's because any other process might be accessing the administration directory while you were doing the update.

Comment: But I am also try this before I restart sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/lock, sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock but It is not work :(

Comment: :Has the problem occurred again?

Comment: Yeah! It is working for one or two times. After that, it shows the same error(Not only for sudo apt-get update also for sudo apt-get install somepackages)

Comment: :Similar answer is here:(http://askubuntu.com/questions/15433/unable-to-lock-the-administration-directory-var-lib-dpkg-is-another-process).

Comment: If you open any GUI package manager and try to run from the command line apt-get you will recive that error since the GUI has apt locked.

Answer (score 1):

This usually happens if another automated process has locked the apt database at the time you are running your command interactively.

Most likely candidates for this (by Ubuntu package name):

- `unattended-upgrades`
- `cron-apt`

but other candidates exist. These are scheduled using `cron` in most cases. Check out `/etc/crontab`, files in `/etc/cron.{d,hourly,daily,weekly,monthly}` as well as user crontabs in `/var/spool/cron/crontabs`.

What to do? Simply wait that the other process is finished. Check for running `dpkg` or other apt-related processes and kill them if they appear hung (consult the logs prior to that).

Comment: I am not use cron-apt thats for sure! And I am also trying to kill the running apt-related process by following command sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/lock, sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock but It is not work. Is there any other way that I can kill that running dpkg or other apt-related processes. If it is exist please tell me.

Comment: @BEN10: *removing* those files is **not going to kill**  any processes. And removing the files will remove a clue for other apt-related processes that start automatically (like outlined in my answer). To kill the processes you can use `pkill dpkg`, for example. But this is **dangerous** as it can leave your system in a half-configured state. Equally dangerous is to *remove* lock files without making sure that the respective processes don't run anymore. Check with `fuser` or `lsof` what processes use those lock files **first**, then take action. Anything else is reckless and dangerous.